# Multiply mode in SpriteBatch

Tags: xna, lighting, monogame

I have a "lighting" texture (black background with white or colours for lights) that I want to draw as a multiplcation operation. `SpriteBatch.Begin` can specify `BlendState.Additive`, but there's no `BlendState.Multiplicative`.

I also tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982741/how-to-multiply-two-sprites-in-spritebatch-draw-xna-2d), but it didn't work -- even when I (incorrectly?) changed the code to work with XNA 4 style `ColorDestinationBlend`, I ended up with the final solution being inverted (black area where the light is, everything else is visible).

I initially thought of a shader, but I couldn't get shaders to work with MonoGame, so I'm falling back to `SpriteBatch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own BlendState, eg:

```
BlendState blend = new BlendState();
blend.ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add;
blend.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
blend.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero;
```

This will result in out.rgb = source.rgb * destination.rgb + 0;

**Edits by questioner:** I had to also set the drawing mode to `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` before this worked.